# Stored Procedure Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting a bit clueless about this thing in SQL Server. I m not sure whether this is possible or not.

Well, all I m looking for is as below

- If my stored procedure returns some results then , display some output
- Else display nothing

Something like

```
IF EXEC (@temp) THEN 'The results are present'
ELSE ''
END IF
```

Any input on this , would be helpful !!!

Thanks !!!

Comment: You can check record count return from your SP, if count = 0, then '' else 'The results are present'

Comment: Yup , i was googling and searching through MSDN with the syntax that helps me with that .... But could not locate it !!! Thanks

Comment: Thanks , I got that         IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0  
        PRINT 'Results obtained'
       ELSE
        PRINT ''

Answer (score 1):

Take a temporary table, and insert whatever data the stored procedure returns into it. This way you will end up writing

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable(col1,col2) SELECT val1,val2 FROM table1
```

instead of only

```
SELECT val1,val2 FROM table1
```

at the end just check for no of records in temp table

```
if exists(select * from @temptable)
 print'stored procedure returned some data'
else
 print'stored procedure did not return data'
```